# VB.NET Web Form Project Reference Issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a project solution having multiple class library projects and one main web application which have the project reference for the other class library project.

The class libraries have the 2.0 framework but the web application have 4.0 framework.

For e.g.

```
Ecommerce.GoogleCheckout (Class Library/2.0 Framework)
Ecommerce.IV1.Core (Class Library/2.0 Framework)
Website (Web Application/4.0 Framework)
```

I cannot change the framework for the class library project as this project is already developed and have many dependencies, I have got this project for maintenance.

The problem is when I added new classes in one of the class library project and build the project individually it compiles perfectly but when I build the whole solution it gives the following error-

```
Type 'Ecommerce.IV1.Core.Catalog.xxxxxxxxx' is not defined.
```

I have added the proper import statements to access the project namespaces-

```
Imports Ecommerce.IV1.Core
```

All the other classes from the same directory/namespace are properly accessible in the web application project

Please let me know if any more information it required. Any help or guidance would be appreciated as I have very tight timelines.

Regards,

Manik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your app.config for the following configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Make sure that useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy is set to true.